# Nodejs net.createServer detect when data is done

Tags: javascript, node.js, server

Say that I use `net.createServer` in Node.js to create a server like so:

```
'use strict';

var net = require('net'),
    serverPort = 1024,
    serverHost = 'localhost',
    server;

server = net.createServer(function (socket) {
    var whole = '';
    console.log('Client connected.');
    socket.setEncoding('utf8');
    socket.on('data', function (data) {
        console.log('Received data.');
        whole += data;
    });
    socket.on('end', function () {
        console.log('Client disconnected.');
    });
});

server.listen(serverPort, serverHost, function () {
    console.log('Server listening at ' + serverHost + ':' + serverPort);
});
```

I create a connection to this server in an external program and send it a big string. "Received data." is printed 4 times. How can I definitively know when the entire string has been received by the server? The `end` event is only called when the client disconnects, not when he is done sending his big string.

Comment: 'end' will be emitted when the source sends a FIN packet. You could create a readable stream and listen for 'end' on that. https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_readable

Comment: @Billy I don't understand what you are suggesting, I tried `var readable = new Readable(); socket.pipe(readable); readable.on('data', function () {});` but it threw an error. Could you please provide a code example?